# Djangocms-blog Reverse for 'post-detail' not found in another languages

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I wrote a cms plugin that show a blog details and link. it work's on the EN language but in FA `post.get_absolute_url()` has a error, that says: **Reverse for 'post-detail' not found. 'post-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

I'm using djangocms-blog==1.2.3, django==3.2.20 and djangocms==3.11.3

My *models.py*:

```
class ArticleView(CMSPlugin):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="article_view")`
```

My *cms_plugins.py*:

```
@plugin_pool.register_plugin
class ArticleViewPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = ArticleView
    name = _("Article View Plugin")
    render_template = "article_view.html"
    cache = False
```

In my *article_view.html*:

```
<a class="fusion-link-wrapper" href="{{ instance.post.get_absolute_url }}"aria-label="{{ instance.post.title }}"></a>
```

My *urls.py*:

```
from cms.sitemaps import CMSSitemap
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from django.urls import include, path
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = [path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': {'cmspages':
    CMSSitemap}}), path('', include('djangocms_blog.taggit_urls')),]
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(path('admin/', admin.site.urls), path('',
    include('cms.urls')), path('taggit_autosuggest/', include('taggit_autosuggest.urls')))
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
        )
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.
        STATIC_ROOT)
```

error image:
[image]

I tried to change languages in settings and rebuild the FA page but nothing happened

Comment: Share the `urls.py` and `Post` model.

Comment: Post model is from djangocms-blog @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike

Comment: Have you published the content in each language?